# Pegar o início e fim do registro da jornada

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho a seguinte situação:

Tenho o seguinte fiddle, com as matrículas e marcações de registro das pessoas.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1405c/20

Tentei fazer esse segundo fiddle:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1405c/17

Porém não está pegando os valores corretos de início de jornada. E também não consigo pegar o final da jornada.

Eu precisava retornar algo assim:

```
|      |                    |    |                     |                     |inicio |fim    |
| matr | nome               |dia | inicio              | fim                 |turno  |turno  |
|------|--------------------|----|---------------------|---------------------|-------|-------|
| 1646 | VINICIUS D         | 17 | 2019-01-17 08:23:21 | 2019-01-17 19:36:39 | 08:00 | 18:00 |
| 1646 | VINICIUS D         | 18 | 2019-01-18 08:45:01 | 2019-01-18 19:34:48 | 08:00 | 18:00 |
| 9076 | ANTUERPIO C        | 16 | 2019-01-16 05:53:51 | 2019-01-16 05:53:59 | 07:00 | 17:00 |
| 9076 | ANTUERPIO C        | 17 | 2019-01-17 07:45:25 | 2019-01-17 07:45:33 | 07:00 | 17:00 |
| 9076 | ANTUERPIO C        | 18 | 2019-01-18 05:51:35 | 2019-01-18 17:54:49 | 07:00 | 17:00 |
| 9076 | ANTUERPIO C        | 19 | 2019-01-19 07:16:05 | 2019-01-19 07:16:08 | 07:00 | 17:00 |
| 1786 | FABIO C            | 17 | 2019-01-17 18:56:21 | 2019-01-18 05:01:27 | 19:00 | 05:00 |
| 777  | CARLOS A           | 17 | 2019-01-17 20:01:46 | 2019-01-17 20:01:46 | 20:00 | 06:00 |
| 777  | CARLOS A           | 18 | 2019-01-18 19:50:22 | 2019-01-18 19:50:22 | 20:00 | 06:00 |
```

Ps: A coluna dia, início turno e fim turno são apenas indicativos para compreensão, não é necessário retorná-las.